# Error occurs while compiling C++ project on VS11 with Bullseye Coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2012, bullseye

**Error occurs while compiling C++ project on VS11 with Bullseye Coverage. Error message is:**

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.5.4 Windows License 6960 
1>  Copyright (c) Bullseye Testing Technology 1990-2012
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\collection.h(50): error : expected ';', near 'new'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

**Does anybody run into this problem? Can you give me some suggestion to sovle it?**

Comment: Show us some code. Especially collection.h, line 50 +/- 10 lines.

Answer (score 1):

There were many errors in coverage builds when VS11 was just released. Try updating the Bullseye to the latest version, errors should be fixed there.

Comment: For future searchers. I tried using VS2019 with a back version of Bullseye, 8.15.16, and got a similar error. Moving to 8.20.5 fixed it.